# sqoop | getting nullpointerexception while running sqoop import tool

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to import mysql table into hive using sqoop 1.4.7. Command I have executed

***`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sb --username root --password xxxx --table sb_user --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table sqoop_import.test_from_sqoop --fields-terminated-by "," --bindir ./`***

But getting the below exception

```
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
18/04/03 22:44:56 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
18/04/03 22:44:56 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/04/03 22:44:56 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
18/04/03 22:44:56 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/04/03 22:44:57 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sb_user` AS t LIMIT 1
18/04/03 22:44:57 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sb_user` AS t LIMIT 1
18/04/03 22:44:57 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop
Note: ./sb_user.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18/04/03 22:44:58 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: ./sb_user.jar
18/04/03 22:44:58 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListing(FileListing.java:67)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListing(FileListing.java:39)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.addClassFilesFromDir(CompilationManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.jar(CompilationManager.java:378)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:108)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

But I can execute the below command successfully

***`sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/information_schema --username root -password xxxx`***

Please help me here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in `--bindir ./` option. Sqoop tries to recursively add all contents inside `./` (https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/util/FileListing.java#L72). Check this dir or just change it.

Comment: Jesus, how can you find this ??
However, you still didn't describe the solution. Thanks a lot.